# MongoDB query array elements

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to Mongodb,trying to fetch data from a collections ,firstly i need to get all the values of array "1" from the below example,without passing any value of array and secondly get data in Json format ,which will be sent to a client via cursor, toArray function works for console but not for html page.

Code:

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5934f65bdab27e02aa954891"),"tracker" : [ 
    {

        "1" : [ 
            "open", 
            "isnot", 
            "closed", 
            "any"
        ],
        "2" : [ 
            "task", 
            "user story", 
            "bug", 
            "support", 
            "feature", 
            "ui modification", 
            "enhancment", 
            "use case"
        ]
    }
],
"subject" : [ 
    {
        "1" : [ 
            "contains", 
            "doesnot contain", 
            "none", 
            "any"
        ]
    }
]}
```

Expected Output_1(values of array "1" ):
    "open","isnot","closed", "any"

Expected Output_2(Json format)

```
"tracker" : [ 
{
    "1" : [ 
        "open", 
        "isnot", 
        "closed", 
        "any"
    ],
    "2" : [ 
        "task", 
        "user story", 
        "bug", 
        "support", 
        "feature", 
        "ui modification", 
        "enhancment", 
        "use case"
    ]
}],"subject" : [ 
{
    "1" : [ 
        "contains", 
        "doesnot contain", 
        "none", 
        "any"
    ]
}]}
```

Comment: Since you do not know the syntax, it's probably best if you show what you expect the result of your "query" to be here. Also explain if this should be from a "single" document or from "many".

Comment: It's JSON not "jason". And you are being asked to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44366843/edit) your question and show us the output format of the document you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.details.aggregate(

    // Pipeline
    [
        // Stage 1
        {
            $match: {"_id" : ObjectId("5934f65bdab27e02aa954891")}
        },

        // Stage 2
        {
            $unwind: "$tracker"
        },

        // Stage 3
        {
            $project: {
                'tracker.1':1
            }
        },

    ]
);
```

Above aggregate query executes following aggregation stages sequentially in pipeline

- $match operator filters document to select only document where value
  of _id field is equivalent to specific Object Id
- $unwind operator splits an array field into separate documents for
  each value of array.
- $project operator limits fields returned into result.